# Does a large PHP file execute way faster than a tiny, cut-down one?

Tags: php, execution

I "inherited" from a collegue a large PHP script: inside there's a large switch (based on the value of a POST variable the code executes related actions). Since the file is a little unreadable (about 2300 lines), I thought to refactor anything, creating multiple independent files. While working, I wandered: aside from the readability of the code, does the length of a PHP file has an impact on performances too? Of course, I know each single file can contain code less or more intensive (in itself), but, given two big files starting with the same code, if I cut 95% of the content of one of the two, will the "slim" be executed way faster? Or it's the same?

Comment: A couple of big files compared to a few more but smaller files won't matter at all, unless you have a _really_ slow file system. If you're using OOP and auto loading, like PSR-4, then having more small classes is always better, since nothing will be loaded unless it's needed. Having all in one file would load everything on every request, even if it isn't needed.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's more important to make the code more maintainable, (which in my opinion, a file with a few thousand rows isn't) than starting to micro optimize the code before it's needed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: they told me they started with a very little switch (three cases), but they ended up updating the file, adding more and more cases. I would like to "destructure" this thing   :-)

Comment: Sounds like they basically "quick fixed" the code into an un-maintainable mess. I would refactor it all, breaking it up into into multiple files where one file have a clear purpose. Don't worry about 10-20 files vs one big one. If you run into performance issues at some point in the future, I can promise you that the file count won't be the cause.

Comment: `while(true);` is a single line of code that executes forever. Having 1 million lines of if statements will execute faster than that one line. It's never about the file size it's always about what the code does.

Comment: @apokryfos: ok, ok, thanks